# Dividir un campo en varias columnas en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando sobre una tabla de direcciones y necesito poder dividirla en columnas.

```
SELECT Direccion
FROM MiTabla
```

El resultado de esta tabla es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna manera de poder dividir este resultado en varias columnas?, por ejemplo de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano agradezco el que me puedan apoyar.

Comment: Cuál de las dos preguntas idénticas deberíamos mirar? En ninguna se ve que hayas intentado _algo_ para resolver tu problema. En ninguna de las dos indicas qué versión de SQL Server usas. Elige UNA de las dos, la editas para que esté completa y borras la otra, por favor

Comment: si quieres saber si hay alguna forma, si la hay (varias), pero debes definir cuál es tu separador, me refiero a que por ejemplo que quieres unir dos cadenas como 6A y Avenida que estan separadas por un espacio, pero las quieres juntas; así como colonia que deseas hasta 5 cadenas separadas por 1 espacio.

Comment: @lsanchezo
, si es justo lo que necesito hacer, y he intentado varias formas sin embargo ninguna de las que he intentado cumple con lo que necesito, esto debido a que por ejemplo en el primer registro la palabra **avenida** me aparece al principio, pero en el segundo me aparece al final,  y lo que busco es encontrar una manera de hacerlo por medio de un patrón.

Comment: Me atrevo a decir (_con temor a equivocarme_) que no es posible, ya que al parecer, no hay un orden lógico que permita identificar un patrón. Por lo que alcanzo a entender en tu comentario, un registro podría contener **Av. 6A** y el número de la casa podría tener un formato diferente **#4 102**, por poner un ejemplo. Esa lógica se debe pensar desde el modelado de datos. Cada parte de la dirección se debe insertar en campos separados.

Comment: Es casi imposible dividir una dirección en partes de manera confiable. Lo ideal es que consigas una base de datos de direcciones (posiblemente de la empresa postal) y compares la dirección con ella.